# Why is it that I'm unable to retrieve log files when running the Sagemaker pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to debug what is wrong with my python code script (query_exec.py) specifically when I'm running it through the sagemaker pipeline by using the ProcessingStep. The python script works fine if I run it manually without going through sagemaker pipeline. Since I'm trying to debug, I want to be able to retrieve the log files. However, my code below is still not helping me to retrieve the log file.

```
    from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
    from sagemaker.workflow.steps import ProcessingStep
    from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline import Pipeline
    import json
    
    processing_image_uri = 'my-image-uri'
    
    processor = sagemaker.processing.Processor(role = role, image_uri = processing_image_uri, instance_count = 1, instance_type = "ml.t3.medium")
    
    processing_output = ProcessingOutput(destination = "s3://mybucket/tmp/athena_sagemaker", source='/opt/ml/processing/output', output_name = 'datasetcreation-(1)',
                                         s3_upload_mode = "Continuous")
    
    step_process = ProcessingStep(
        name="DatasetCreation",
        processor=processor,
        outputs = [processing_output],
        code = "query_exec.py",
    )
    
    pipeline_name = f"DatasetCreation"
    pipeline = Pipeline(
        name=pipeline_name,
       
        steps=[step_process],
    )
    
    json.loads(pipeline.definition())
    
    pipeline.upsert(role_arn = role)
    
    execution = pipeline.start()
    
    execution.describe()
    
    execution.wait()
```

I still don't see any log files in the S3 bucket path. Would greatly appreciate if someone can help me to spot where I went wrong. Been stuck here for quite long. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[Troubleshooting Amazon SageMaker Model Building Pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipelines-troubleshooting.html)

Comment: I actually can run the sagemaker pipeline successfully (but it did not function as expected behind the scenes, that's why I'm trying to find what's the issue through logs) but I'm not able to retrieve any logs when I tried to look for it in CloudWatch @gshpychka

Answer (score 2):

In your query_exec.py you can add the following lines to be able to log anything you want:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

And then:
logger.info("print something")
```

You can also simply use `print("print something")` when it's needed.

The the logging of your file will be displayed in the **Sagemaker -> Processing -> ProcessingJobs** -> click on the job name -> click on **view logs**.

Wait couple of seconds until you see something in the **Log streams** sections, then click on that.
Now you will see all the logs for processing query_exec.py file.